# Java8 pass a method as parameter using lambda

Tags: java, methods, lambda, java-8, parameter-passing

I would like to create a class that store a list of methods references and then executes all of them using Java 8 Lambda but I have some problem.

This is the class

```
public class MethodExecutor {
    //Here I want to store the method references
    List<Function> listOfMethodsToExecute = new LinkedList<>();

    //Add a new function to the list
    public void addFunction(Function f){
       if(f!=null){
            listOfMethodsToExecute.add(f);
       }
    }

    //Executes all the methods previously stored on the list
    public void executeAll(){
        listOfMethodsToExecute.stream().forEach((Function function) -> {
            function.apply(null);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class that I created for test

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MethodExecutor me = new MethodExecutor();
        me.addFunction(this::aMethod);
        me.executeAll();    
    }

    public void aMethod(){
        System.out.println("Method executed!");
    }
}
```

But there is something wrong when I pass `this::aMethod` using `me.addFunction`.

What is wrong?

Comment: `But there is something wrong when I pass this::aMethod` - it's because there is a mistake somewhere. If you want more specific answer - give more specific question.

Comment: Post the specific error you're getting and a more specific question

Comment: A [`Function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) takes an argument and has a return value. `aMethod` has neither.

Comment: And how can I manage methods that have no arguments and no return value?

Comment: If at some point you want to use a `Function` (as defined in the java.util.function package) make sure to provide type arguments, as in `Function<String,Integer>` (or whatever). The examples here use the `Function` raw type, which will effectively disable type inference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should provide a suitable functional interface which abstract method signature is compatible with your method reference signature. In your case it seems that `Runnable` instead of `Function` should be used:

```
public class MethodExecutor {
    List<Runnable> listOfMethodsToExecute = new ArrayList<>();

    //Add a new function to the list
    public void addFunction(Runnable f){
       if(f!=null){
            listOfMethodsToExecute.add(f);
       }
    }

    //Executes all the methods previously stored on the list
    public void executeAll(){
        listOfMethodsToExecute.forEach(Runnable::run);
    }
}
```

Also note that in static `main` method `this` is not defined. Probably you wanted something like this:

```
me.addFunction(new Test()::aMethod);
```

Comment: You don’t need a `stream()` to run all elements. Just `listOfMethodsToExecute.forEach(Runnable::run);`

Answer (score 4):

You can't refer to `this` in a `static` context as there is no `this`

```
me.addFunction(this::aMethod);
```

You need to refer to an instance or define your Function to take a Test object.

```
public void addFunction(Function<Test, String> f){
   if(f!=null){
        listOfMethodsToExecute.add(f);
   }
}
```

and

```
me.addFunction(Test::aMethod);
```